# Alt code being returned instead of int C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a project for a C++ class, and the assignment is as follows. **Create a program that reads a file of presidents, and ask the user to guess the correct value for the selected president.**
We were given a .txt file that has all the data, and is in the file like so.

```
1
George Washington
(1732 to 1799)
April 30, 1789
March 4, 1797
Independent
Commander-in-Chief; of the Continental Army (1775 to 1783)
John Adams                          
2
John Adams
(1735 to 1826)
March 4, 1797
March 4, 1801
Federalist
Vice President
Thomas Jefferson
```

The top number being the president number, 2nd being their name, 3rd being their birthdate and death date, 4th being the day they took office, 5th being when they left office, 6th being party, 7th being previous office held, and 7th being their vice president. Here's the code for the method that reads the file.

```
void presidentGame::readPresidents(){

        string fileName = "presidents.txt";
        string strNum, name, birthDeath, tookOffice, leaveOffice, party, previousOffice, vicePresident;
        int num;
        ifstream inFile(fileName);
        if (! inFile) {
            cout << "Failed to find the file " << fileName  << endl;
        }
        else {
            while (getline(inFile, strNum)){
                num = stoi(strNum);  //I did this because an actual int is better than a string
                getline(inFile, name);
                getline(inFile, birthDeath);
                getline(inFile, tookOffice);
                getline(inFile, leaveOffice);
                getline(inFile, party);
                getline(inFile, previousOffice);
                getline(inFile, vicePresident);
                president tempPresident(num, name, birthDeath,tookOffice, leaveOffice, party, previousOffice, vicePresident);
                presidents.push_back(tempPresident);
            }
        }
}
```

The problem that is occurring, is that num, is being displayed as an Alt code value in command prompt. Here's an example of the output when you answer correctly.

```
***********************************************
Correct Incorrect       Total Guesses
======= =========       =============
0          11                 11
Guess which President Thomas Jefferson was? <♥> 3

Congrats, You finally got one right!

Thomas Jefferson was the ♥rd President

President Information:
============================
He lived from (1743 to 1826)
He took office March 4, 1801
He left office on March 4, 1809
His party was Democratic-Republican
His previous office held was Vice PresidentHis vice president was 1st term: Aaro
n Burr / 2nd term: George Clinton
Press any key to continue...
```

So instead of displaying the number as "3", it displayed it at alt+NUM_3, which is ♥. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem is most likely in the output code that you haven't shown us.  Maybe you're trying to print an integer value using a string format?

Comment: How about showing us the code that outputs the text.

Comment: You probably display a `char` initialized with the value of `int`. Post the displaying code. Unrelated: use [`std::vector::emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) instead of pushing temporaries in the vector.

Comment: The problem is in the `president` class, you've probably used `int8_t` or `char` instead of `int` for the president's number.

Comment: @vsoftco Or simply call `presidents.push_back(president(...))`, which will call `push_back(president&&)`, that will be as fast as `emplace_back()` if proper move constructor is defined. But I think that's a matter of taste.

Comment: You shouldn't post a question and run away without reacting to the feedback...

Comment: @Antonio, I accepted the answer that worked. How is that not feedback? Plus, I wasn't watching it very closely since I posted this before going into a class. I wasn't able to post feedback 50 minutes after posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the outputting code, there are a number of reasons why this could happen. But most likely, you have something like this going on:

```
string outputBuffer = presidentName;
outputBuffer += " was the ";
outputBuffer += presidentNumber; // The problem is here.
outputBuffer += getSuffix(presidentNumber); // Or whatever logic you have for this
outputBuffer += " President";
```

The fix is simple:

```
outputBuffer = to_string(presidentNumber); // Replace the problem line with this
```

C++ is pretty good with type detection, but it's still a strong type language. The compiler interprets `presidentNumber` as a literal character and without error (although depending on your compiler and flags you may get a warning).

So if `presidentNumber = 65`, that represents an "A" character. (Never mind the fact that there's not a 65th president, just an example).

**Examples**

Before: http://cpp.sh/2tjj

After: http://cpp.sh/8izy

Comment: @MooingDuck he's got you there

Comment: Huh.  Well.  Things Known +1.